# How to add a new ssh key to Gitolite

Tags: ssh, gitolite, authorized-keys

I simply want to add a new key. So I added it in the keydir, set the permissions in the gitolite conf, committed and pushed, but nothing.

At what point does the new key get added to the .ssh authorized-keys file? Because it seems the new key never makes it in there and that's why the person using the key cannot get access...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At what point does the new key get added to the .ssh authorized-keys file?

Immediately after the push, provided your key:

- is a public key (one line similar to `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAA...hFvETUVDvF2iZ`)
- is name after the name of the resource who will access gitolite: `tom.pub`

As the [OP Dee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2890471/dee) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246659/how-to-add-a-new-ssh-key-to-gitolite/25246819#comment39333302_25246819), the issue was in the public key filename representing the user:

> the only error is bad username and i think this is because I used a '`/`' in the name of a group of user

Indeed, the [username pattern](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/dc8b590a0562ab7dc4bdab9511fe6c31cb422ae8/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L53) is:

```
^\@?[0-9a-zA-Z][-0-9a-zA-Z._\@+]*$
```

No '`/`' allowed.

Comment: cool. my key satisfies these requirements. any idea why it may not be working?

Comment: @Dee you can check the `~git/.gitolite/logs` folder and see if there is any recent log that might explain why the public key wasn't processed.

Comment: the only error is bad username and i think this is because i used a '/' in the name of a group of users... would that be the reason?

Comment: aha, seems that was the reason. thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Dee I have edited the answer to add a link to the gitolite source detailing the regex pattern used for the username.